# R apply function with vector names to every row

Tags: r, apply

I want to calculate the average time between elements in a row of a `data.frame`.

```
> x <- structure(list(`as.Date("2010-12-31")` = structure(c(14974, 14974, 
14974, 14974, 14974), class = "Date"), Date1_P2 = structure(c(14061, 
11566, 11747, 13848, 12965), class = "Date"), Date2_P2 = structure(c(NA, 
10408, 11627, 10074, 6329), class = "Date"), Date3_P2 = structure(c(NA, 
8370, 11566, NA, NA), class = "Date")), .Names = c("as.Date(\"2010-12-31\")", 
"Date1_P2", "Date2_P2", "Date3_P2"), row.names = c("0000001.1", 
"0000004.2", "0000005.2", "0000009.3", "0000010.1"), class = "data.frame")
> x
          as.Date("2010-12-31")   Date1_P2   Date2_P2   Date3_P2
0000001.1            2010-12-31 2008-07-01       <NA>       <NA>
0000004.2            2010-12-31 2001-09-01 1998-07-01 1992-12-01
0000005.2            2010-12-31 2002-03-01 2001-11-01 2001-09-01
0000009.3            2010-12-31 2007-12-01 1997-08-01       <NA>
0000010.1            2010-12-31 2005-07-01 1987-05-01       <NA>
```

I have written a function that calculates this for each row.

```
> avgtime <- function(history){
  difftime <- vector("numeric", length=9)
  i <- 2
  while(!is.na(history[i]) & i < 4){
    difftime[i-1] <- history[i-1] - history[i]
    i <- i + 1
  }
  return(mean((unlist(difftime[which(difftime!=0)]))))
}
> for(i in 1:nrow(x)){print(avgtime(x[i,]))}
[1] 913
[1] 2283
[1] 1673.5
[1] 2450
[1] 4322.5
```

But when I try to `apply` this to my `data.frame`, I run into problems.

```
> apply(x, 1, avgtime)
Error in history[i - 1] - history[i] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What is the more appropriate `apply` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply`, when used on a data frame, has the effect of coercing it into a matrix. The mode of the matrix is the mode which can store all of the columns of the data frame; in your case, you have columns of class `Date` which means the matrix will be `character`. This is why your `apply` call fails.

What you can do is convert all the (required) columns of `x` to numeric before using `apply`. You're not using any date-specific features of the data so you shouldn't be losing anything.

```
x[] <- lapply(x, unclass)
apply(x, 1, avgtime)
```

A more involved, but possibly more elegant approach (since it doesn't involve coercions or matrix/array manipulations) would be to use `mapply`:

```
mapply(x[,1], x[,2], x[,3], x[,4], avgtime2)
#or
do.call(mapply, c(list(avgtime2), x))
```

where `avgtime2` is a rewritten version of `avgtime` to accept multiple inputs rather than 1.

Comment: I considered `mapply`, but I actually have list about twenty items long, and that was getting tedious.